# How to remove a third party software that is installed but cannot be located?

Tags: software-uninstall

I have been on Ubuntu 14.04 for a while now. I was looking for a DVD burning software because both Brasero and K3b proved quite unsatisfactory. Eventually I located Nero Linux 4.0 on the internet and downloaded it. When I tried to install it, I was led to the Software Manager even though Nero Linux is not listed under it. The Software Manager warned me that the application (Nero Linux) is of poor quality and can severely harm the computer. But since I desperately needed a DVD burner, I decided I would "Try Ubuntu" from the Ubuntu installation disc, install the Nero Linux within it and see how it goes. To my great relief, it worked so well that I decided to install it permanently. However, before doing so I wanted to make sure how to uninstall it -- in case something should go wrong. And in this I was utterly surprised, since the Nero Linux, although installed and working, could not even be located anywhere -- neither by the Terminal nor by the Software Manager!!

I would appreciate it if anyone having more experience with Ubuntu could provide some help in this regard. Can it be that the application,though not traceable now, will show up  in a regular Ubuntu Operating system and it will then be possible to remove it like any other software?

Answer (score 2):

Try this`sudo apt-get autoremove nero` you may have to replace "nero" with the correct package name.

OR You can try synaptic package manager `sudo apt-get install synaptic` start it from dash an search "nero"

Good luck

Answer (score 1):

This should find it if it is a package in the apt manager

```
$ apt-cache showpkg *nero*
```

You could do a search for it as well

```
$ locate nero
```

if you want to see where is is running the binary you can try

```
$ which nero
```

If its running a process somewhere you can find the process with

```
$ ps aux | grep 'nero'
```

Just delete the binary "/usr/bin/nero" it has no install package so cannot be uninstalled with apt

Comment: I have just tried all of these -- to no avail. Only the 3rd led to "user/bin/nero" but there the trail ended. Could it be that it's not showing up in "Try Ubuntu" but will do so if installed within my permanent Ubuntu OS?

Comment: You might as well just delete the binary at user/bin/nero I doubt it will break anything

Answer (score 0):

You can remove it through Software Center or from Synaptic package manager by finding the nero package.

You can also remove it from terminal.

```
sudo apt-get --purge remove nero*
```

But don't worry it will not harm your system. I am using it from 3 months, having no issue.

Comment: As I said I had already tried apt-get (as well as Software Manager since it got installed by it). It seems to me too that it will do no harm, still I ought to know how to remove it. One important question: **since you have installed it and have been using it, could you please check whether it can be located in your system and whether any clue is available there as to the method of its removal?**

Answer (score -2):

I have the way it works for me.
I had downloaded messenger for the desktop app from chrome.
But, I too couldn't locate its destination. However, I could locate it as below:

`$ cd`             # Takes you to root.

`$ cd /usr/bin`    # Locates and navigates to the `bin` directory.

`$ ls`             # Opens the directory and files/folders present
in `bin`,And here is where you can locate your
third party application or whatever is located.

```
$ sudo rm <app-to-delete>
```

---

**NB:** It helped me to remove the "`messenger for desktop`" app.

Comment: `cd` on its own takes you to your home directory, not `/` (root) - unless you are logged in as root (and happen to have `/` as your home directory).